# In php , is there a way to trace a variable?

Tags: php, debugging, variables, xdebug, stack-trace

I have this variable in a big php script that I want to trace back to where/when and what value it was instantiated.  Is there a function/api or debugging techniques to do this?

Comment: There's quite simply `-d`[`xdebug.collect_assignments=1`](http://xdebug.org/docs/execution_trace) for a quick overview.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're using PHPStorm you can set breakpoints and inspect the values of variables.

http://blog.jetbrains.com/phpstorm/2013/12/just-in-time-debugging-and-php-exception-breakpoints-with-phpstorm-and-xdebug/

You'll need xdebug installed as well.

Comment: yes i know, but is there a way to do this w/o a debugger like xdebug?

Comment: I'm not aware of a way to do this without a JIT debugger.

Answer (score -2):

You can use debug_print_backtrace() function.
http://php.net/manual/en/function.debug-print-backtrace.php

```
<?php


function f1() {
    f2();
}

function f2() {
    f3();
}

function f3(){
    echo "<pre>";
    debug_print_backtrace();
    echo "</pre>";
}

f1();

?>
```

Output:

```
#0  f3() called at [/home/xfiddlec/public_html/main/code_47406510.php:9]
#1  f2() called at [/home/xfiddlec/public_html/main/code_47406510.php:5]
#2  f1() called at [/home/xfiddlec/public_html/main/code_47406510.php:18]
```

Comment: If this is verified as correct, I'm upvoting this a million times

Comment: this does not trace back a variable, just a where the debug_print_backtrace() is called.